# Can composition of many kernels express any covariance matrix in gaussian process?

Tags: covariance-matrix, kernel-trick, gaussian-process

Now I'am studying a gaussian process.

Recently, I wondered that whether covariance function which made by kernel function can express any arbitrary covariance matrix or not.

My question is: 
Is composition of kernels be able to represent any arbitrary covariance matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The space of covariance matrices is the space of positive semi definite matrices and any positive semi definite matrix can be written as $K=\phi \phi^T$, hence can be written as the product in a Hilbert space. The kernel function simply takes the product in a Hilbert space so yes you can.